# Reads data correctly but writes incorrectly

Tags: c++, file, read-write

I am trying to read specific binary data (2 Bytes) of a file and this mission works well, the problem when rewriting that (2 Bytes) again in the same place. Unfortunately, it changes the entire file data to zeros.

Look at the following two screenshots:

**Data before writing:**

[image]

**Data after writing:**

[image]

**The code:**

```
bool myClass::countChanger() {
    std::ifstream sggFileObj_r(this->sggFilePath, std::ios::binary);   
    if (!sggFileObj_r.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    // Buffer variable
    unsigned short count;
    // Move the file pointer to offset 4
    sggFileObj_r.seekg(4);
    // Reading data 
    sggFileObj_r.read((char*)&count, sizeof(unsigned short));
    sggFileObj_r.close();
    //// ---------------------- ////
    std::ofstream sggFileObj_w(this->sggFilePath, std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
    // Increase the buffer variable by one
    count += 1;
    // Move the file pointer again to offset 4
    sggFileObj_w.seekp(4);
    // Rewriting data again to the file after modification
    sggFileObj_w.write((char*)&count, sizeof(unsigned short));
    sggFileObj_w.close();
    return true;
}
```

**Why did that happen and how to resolve?**

---

**UPDATE**:

I have appended `std::ios::app` to file mode, and zeros problem solved but the specific data that I want to update is not updated.

Comment: Does the file size also change to `0`?  IIRC opening in binary mode will still truncate wipe out the existing file if it exists.

Comment: You opened the file for writing.  Of course the file will disappear on you.

Comment: @NathanOliver: No, the file size stays as is.

Comment: Try using `std::ofstream sggFileObj_w(this->sggFilePath, std::ios::binary | std::ios::app)` and then seek to the beginning and then to where you need to be.

Comment: @NathanOliver: After insert `std::ios::app` the problem solved but unfortunately, the specific binary data (2 Bytes) is not updated as I want.

Comment: Could you update your post with the new code that doesn't zero out the file?  Could just be a seeking issue since you start at the end of the file so you need to get back to where you want to write the data.

Comment: @NathanOliver: this `sggFileObj_w.seekp(4)` will make the file pointer get back to the target data position.

Comment: @LionKing Yep.  I've added an answer that tells you why that doesn't work.  Let me know if you have any further issues.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
std::ofstream sggFileObj_w(this->sggFilePath, std::ios::binary)
```

will wipe out the data in the file since that is what `ofstream` does by default.  You can use

```
std::ofstream sggFileObj_w(this->sggFilePath, std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
```

to stop the data from being overridden but the issue with this is that file stream starts at the end of the file and pretends like the rest of the file doesn't exist, so you can seek back to the beggining and overwrite its contents.

What you can do instead is use a `fstream` like

```
std::fstream sggFileObj_w(this->sggFilePath, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out | std::ios::in);
```

To open the file in binary mode from the beginning without losing any contents.  Then you can seek to where you want to write into the file.

Comment: I was using the last way In the beginning but some problems occurred with that way so, I decided to use each one (read, write) separately.